# Why the thrid parameter of the wcstok_s function is a dimensional pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory

The wcstok_s function is how to achieve?

The wcstok function has only two parameters and how to save the string when call it in the second time and the first parameter is 'null'.

These two are how to return a pointer and the function is finished and why the temporary memory is reserved and it will return a *wchar string ending with '\0';

This is my incorrect code：

```
TCHAR *mywtok(TCHAR *tszText, int x, TCHAR *tnext) {
    TCHAR res[1005];
    if (tszText == nullptr)
        tszText = tnext;
    int len = wcslen(tszText);
    int rlen = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (tszText[i] != x) {
            res[rlen++] = tszText[i];
        }
        else {
            res[rlen] = '\0';
            tnext = tszText + i;
            return res;
        }
    }
    res[rlen] = '\0';
    tnext = nullptr;
    return res;
}
```

The wcstok_s is ignore "",such as ",,a," it will return "a",if i want the return "" then "a" or "","","a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which pointer tnext points to should be modified at the end of the function to hold a pointer at the character following end of the last token matched, so you can loop over all the matches as in this exemple :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx

So, to answer to your question, it is a pointer to a pointer because the function needs to modify the pointer pointer to allow loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
TCHAR *mywtok(TCHAR *tszText, TCHAR *ch, TCHAR **tnext) {
    TCHAR res[1005];
    if (tszText == nullptr)
        tszText = *tnext;
    int len = wcslen(tszText);
    int rlen = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (tszText[i] != ch[0]) {
            res[rlen++] = tszText[i];
        }
        else {
            res[rlen] = '\0';
            *tnext = tszText + i+1;
            wcscpy_s(tszText, wcslen(res)+1, res);
            return tszText;
        }
    }
    res[rlen] = '\0';
    tnext = nullptr;
    wcscpy_s(tszText, wcslen(res)+1, res);
    return tszText;
}
```

The pointer just modify its values,the pointer to pointer can make a pointer point other position.

But why the wcstok function have only two parameter also can use nullptr to first parameter?